# Find Rows with same values in certain colums

Tags: sql

How can I find the rows with the same date and type values in a table?

table:

```
id   dt                      type
30   2020-12-26 15:07:00     9
30   2020-12-26 15:07:00     7
30   2020-12-26 15:07:00     9
```

I want to find only:

```
30   2020-12-26 15:07:00     9
30   2020-12-26 15:07:00     9
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use the group by dt, type with a having count()>1, if the sql dialect you're using permits this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by dt, type) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

Note:  You might also want to include the `id`.  It is not clear if that is part of what makes a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, the id needs to match as well. So same id and type and date

Comment: @drewt . . . Then include `id` in the `partition by`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at sample data and expected output, It seems you want `exists` as follows:

```
Select distinct id, dt, type
  From your_table  t
 where exists 
       (select 1 from yout_table tt
         where tt.id = t.id and tt.type = t.type and tt.dt = t.dt)
```